# Can't get a Youtube background video script in an IF statement.(Javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, desktop

I have 2 working scripts, the first using the youtube player api: 
(#container_home contains a logo showing after the video ends)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#container_home").hide();
$("#player").hide();
});

// create youtube player

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
          controls: 'false',    
          videoId: 'kCdFqMJPqyQ',
          playerVars: {
             'showinfo': 0, 
             'rel': 0, 
             'controls': 0},
          events: {
             'onReady': onPlayerReady,
             'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }

        });
    }


// autoplay video


function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
        $("#player").fadeTo( "fast" , 1);
        $(".jay_load").hide();
        }
function onClick(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();    
        }

// when video ends

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {
            $("#player").hide();          
            $("#container_home").show(2000);
        }
    }
```

And the second tells me if I'm using a desktop computer or another device (using wurfl script):

```
$.getScript("//wurfl.io/wurfl.js")
.done(function()    {

$.wurfl = WURFL;
if ($.wurfl.form_factor === 'Desktop') { 
    alert ('yes'); 

};
});
```

So my goal is to run the youtube script only on desktop browsers.
I tried to copy the first script and paste it over

```
alert ("yes");
```

But thats not working. I hope someone can help me. 
Thanx!

Comment: Was the `$(document).ready` part outside the WURFL script when you tried pasting it?

Comment: It seems that the functions in your first script need to be on the _top level_, i.e. _not nested inside another function_.

Comment: @Xufox thanx for the comments. Can you give me a short example on how to get the functions on the top level in my case? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t really test this… you’d have to put empty functions where they are now (script 1) and redefine them above the `alert` in the WURFL script, but I’m not sure whether the YouTube API will accept that and I’m not sure whether everything will work flawlessly then…

Comment: @Xufox I'll try that. Thanx so much.